# React styled-components how styled declared component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I will try explain one more time my problem for better undestanding .
I need styled component whose I wish he was simultaneously method when i can inject props .
I created easier code for this example :

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "./App.css";

const styledInput = styled.input`
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
`;
const Input = props => {
  return <styledInput type="text" />;
};
const App = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      Text : <Input val={1} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: please mention screenshot of your problem for understanding requirement.

Comment: [link]https://imgur.com/a/M5kBLeH

Comment: What is the question? Please show some code, what you want an example of? How to declare styled component?

Comment: That is a functional component. https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/react-functional-components/

Comment: @Antonio its good way but i wanted do this other . I wanted use styled-components on my declared Component `TextField`

Comment: There is no need to implement additional component for styled-component. You can use `TextField` styled component like normal React components.

Comment: @mattxml whatever you have done in 1st screen that's not right way to work with props and input field, can you please put your code to check?.

Comment: Where are you using the styled element? also may have issues having two variables named Textfield